# SwiftUI: after update to beta 7: using presentationMode raises error: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed

Tags: xcode, swiftui, beta, dismiss

I am working on Mac App and using code like this to dismiss a View:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode : Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is works fine in beta 6 but after beta 7 the review not working and I got this error in runtime: 
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI7BindingV5valuexvg and when I delete this line "self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()" its works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PresentationMode doesn't have a value anymore, it is wrappedValue now. The symbol you are missing is SwiftUI.Binding.value.

Comment: Can you -please- explain how to use it? how to dismiss the view?

Comment: @Nayef: replace `self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()` with `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`